# How to create a materialized view for existing table in Timescale?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

When I'm trying to create materialized view for existing table by query:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW current_data_hourly
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
SELECT id,
        time_bucket(INTERVAL  '1 hour', creation_time) AS creation_time,
       AVG(current_abs_1_avg),
       MAX(current_abs_1_max),
       MIN(current_abs_1_min)
FROM time_series.current_data
GROUP BY id, creation_time;
```

I'm getting:

```
ERROR:  continuous aggregate view must include a valid time bucket function
SQL state: XX000
```

Any suggestions what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view query above, the grouping is ambiguous between the input column name, which is `creation_time` in hypertable `time_series.current_data`, and the output column name, which is defined as `time_bucket(INTERVAL  '1 hour', creation_time) AS creation_time`. According to `GROUP BY` description in [`SELECT` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html):

> In case of ambiguity, a GROUP BY name will be interpreted as an input-column name rather than an output column name.

I.e., `creation_time` is not the one, which is alias for `time_bucker` expression. Thus the error.

One way to fix is to use the positions of the columns from the SELECT clause:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW current_data_hourly
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
SELECT id,
        time_bucket(INTERVAL  '1 hour', creation_time) AS creation_time,
       AVG(current_abs_1_avg),
       MAX(current_abs_1_max),
       MIN(current_abs_1_min)
FROM time_series.current_data
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```